# .NET Core Blazor Dynamically retreive html as string from Razor Page or Blazor Component

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I have a Razor Page (.cshtml) which is a PDF Template. Now i am required to retreive html as string from the page itself to Save it as a PDF file. In MVC, i could use IRazonEngine interface for the same. But in Blazor what can used to obtain this.

Additionally, if i can use Blazor component instead of a Razor Page, how can i get the string of HTML?

Please help!

This is the sample Razor Page I have

```
@model UserModel

        <div>
            <strong>Full Name:</strong>
            <div>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullName)</div>
        </div>
        
            <div>
                <strong>Address:</strong>
                <div>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address);</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <strong>DOB:</strong>
                <div>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateOfBirth);</div>
            </div>
```

**UPDATE :**
I have now used RazorLight.NETCore3 and working smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not about blazor or mvc pages, but you can use [RazorEngine.NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine.NetCore/) library to convert the cshtml and fill in the dynamic data using a model and retrieve the completed html.

Here is a guide on how to do it: https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/generate-outputs-with-razor-engine-in-dotnet-core

Github project: https://github.com/fouadmess/RazorEngine

Here is a simple code which I have used in the past:

```
public string CompileContent(string content, object model)
{
    var stringContent = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(content, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), null, model);
    return stringContent;
}
```

Comment: as per the code here, "string content", here the "content" means the html in text form?

Comment: Yes thats right, you will have to use another library to convert this to pdf - which I assume you already must have in place?

Comment: yes the PDF download is already there, i just needed the html to string dynamic conversion such that i could relay the string to the PDF conversion method. Sir, could you help me to retrieve the html to this content string if possible.

Comment: You can use [`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.1) to read the html as string

Comment: I am now getting "Could not resolve template" issue. Any ideas sir?

Comment: Seems like your file path is not correct? But cant give more information without any code